# How to move block from a region inside of hook_preprocess_node?

Tags: 8, theming, blocks, hooks

I have added `mycustomblock` to the `header` region in our settings `(/admin/structure/block)`. We are using the standard `content` block and displaying that in the `Content` region, which is displayed below the `Header` region.

For just our `Basic Page` content type, we would like to move the `mycustomblock` to display below another field. We tried using the `mymodule_preprocess_node` hook to move the block below one of the fields (i.e. `field_categories`). However, we don't know how to move the block.

**How would we move the block inside the `hook_preprocess_node`?**

Setup:

`Basic Page content type`

- Title
- Categories (field_categories)
- Tags (field_tags)
- Image (field_image)

`node--page--full.html.twig`

```
{{ label }}
{{ content.field_image }}

/* I want to display the block here, using some variable */
{{ mycustomblock_variable }}

{{ content.field_categories }}
{{ content.field_tags }}
```

Regions (order displayed: top down)

1. header
2. content
3. footer

We tried the following but it didn't work

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node($variables) {
  $node = $variables['elements']['#node'];

  if($node->bundle() == 'page') {
    $block_entity = Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load(123456);// BLOCK_ID
    $block_view = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block_content')->view($block_entity, 'mycustomblock');
    $variables['mycustomblock_variable'] = $block_view;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should send render of the block not an array of block entity.
[View](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityViewBuilderInterface.php/function/EntityViewBuilderInterface%3A%3Aview/8.2.x) Method return an array.

Try with `renderer` service like the following:

```
/**
 * Implements hook__preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['elements']['#node'];
  if ($node->bundle() == 'page') {
    $block_entity = Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load(12345);//BLOCK_ID
    $block_view = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getViewBuilder('block_content')
     // Change here default by your block view mode
      ->view($block_entity, 'default');
    $variables['mycustomblock_variable'] =\Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($block_view);
  }
}
```

Comment: the `renderer` service was able to get us what i was looking for.